# Android Firebase query without event

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, querying

I want to retrieve a user from Firebase.

```
 public User findByUserName(String username){
    Query query = this.mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(username);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    return this.user;
}
```

The user is retrieved successfully only if there is a data changing event which makes perfect sense. However, I want to receive my user without changing anything. Is it possible?

If not, why would Firebase offer querying only in case of an event?

Comment: All listeners fire once when first attached, a data change is not needed.  If  `onDataChange()` is not being called, there might be a problem with your security rules.  Add a `Log` statement to `onCancelled()` to see if it is being called.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I was calling the method within a Facebook GraphRequest. It works exactly as you say.